# C send() to socket and select() function

Tags: c, sockets, blocking

I want to `send(socketfd, ...)` and I'm using the `select()` function. Should this file descriptor be in the `writefds`, or in the `readfds`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`readfds` are for sockets you want to read from, `writefds` for those you want to write to. So `writefds` in your case.

Comment: Though, you usually want it in the readfds as well, e.g. so you can gracefully detect when the peer disconnects (read() returning 0)

Comment: okay that's what I know , but I was reading Beej's Guide selectserver.c
[link](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#select) and the last for(j ) loop he'is cheking if j ready for read and use it with send . 
can you help me with that ? @nos too

Comment: That example doesn't care if the write would block. He's only interested in waiting for clients to push data to the server, and then replicates that. The writes could block.